Ubuntu 24.04 + Dell XPS 9350 Lunar Lake (Intel® Core™ Ultra 7 processor 258V Series 2)
Any experience with the XPS 9350 lunar lake? In the Dell support page shows Ubuntu 24.04 as a valid OS:

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS has kernel 6.8, therefore Dell must have implemented some regressions to kernel 6.8 to ensure it works fine with the Intel Lunar Lake processor, same regressions that are already implemented in Kernel 6.13-rc4 (recently released), I know with 6.13-rc2 there were some fixes for Lunar Lake:
https://app.daily.dev/posts/linux-6-13-rc2-released-with-fixes-for-intel-lunar-lake-responsiveness-issues-1m7dl4cj4
I need some guidance with the process to implement those regressions into Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Kernel 6.8) or access to the Dell Ubuntu Recovery image for the 9350 with Lunar Lake, thanks

I don't think "regressions" means what you think it means
